# Selecting class hover after from jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a class called customtooltip, in my css I have

```
.customtooltip:hover::after{

// this emulates a tooltip, so it is a popup with info

}
```

I want to be able to control that from jquery.  Currently I can only select the .customtooltip or use the .hover event on the tooltip, but I want to be able to re-position the popup/tooltip to where the mouse is and I believe I need jquery for this.

thanks,

Comment: You will not be able to use the pseudo element to do this with javascript/jquery

Comment: If you post another question on your specific issue (like "*How can I make pseudo elements follow the mouse?*") you can come up with some workarounds... I have some in mind myself! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; css pseudo-elements don't exist in the DOM, and are therefore inaccessible to JavaScript.

You can retrieve some of the properties, using `window.getComputedStyle()`:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.customtooltip'),
    currentTop = window.getComputedStyle(elem, ':after').top;
```

But you can't *set* properties.

That said, the CSS Pseudo-Elements Module Level 4 starts with:

> 6. Additions to the CSS Object Model
>
> > Pseudo-elements should be reachable by script, stylable from script, and available as event targets.
> >
> > Note We may extend this section in the future to allow creation of pseudo-elements from script.

So, hopefully, this limitation will change in the near future.

References:

- [Pseudo-Elements Module Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-pseudo/#cssom).
- [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle).

Answer (score 0):

For re-positioning your element with class `.customtooltip` you need to first get the mouse position and than changing it according to current.

```
$(".customtooltip").hover(function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    $(this).css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": x,
        "left": y,
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.